# Microsoft excel can not loading images from the server

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2007

I am creating Microsoft excel file and it is used simple html format.
I have used image tag on it and give image link to server images.

When my images is more than 60 (image size 40x40) in excel then after opening the excel gives me error on image place with red X button "The image cannot be displayed. Your computer may not have enough memory to open the image, or the image may have been corrupted"

I have used server image url and images will be downloading when excel will be open.

Can any one have knows how can i handle this issue ? 
my excel version is Microsoft excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solutions for the Excel running in window.
I have used `<input type="image" src="your URL" />` for inserting image in excel and it is working fine in Microsoft Excel 2007
But when i run same in Mac then Microsoft Excel can not display the input control and not loading the images.

I suggest to use the `<input/>` tag instead of `<image/>` tag